# Overflow-x scroll doesn't work properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-water-fintki

As you can see in attached sandbox I have a scrollable div with 6 items aligned in 2 rows.

But when you switch to mobile view (toggle responsive view button near sandbox url input) it starts scrolling vertically.

I've noticed, that if you remove `flex-wrap` it works correctly, but I need this to make 2 rows.

How can I get same behaviour for mobile and desktop?

Comment: You've given the red elements a min width so if they can't fit 3 next to each other they start to wrap. You may be better off with grid - or there may be some definite reason for the minimum width - is there?

Comment: Yes, there will be text inside this div's so I should keep it like that.

I don't understand why it starts scrolling vertically on mobile.

Comment: Or you meant I should use grid instead flexbox?

Comment: The button items now have a width rather than a min-width set. What do you want things to look like when the viewport is too narrow to accommodate  3 items plus their margins? Do you want them to start to go to the next row or do you want them to overflow to the right and the user have to scroll?

Comment: Overflow to have scroll. But it scrolls vertically on mobile instead of horizontal

Comment: I'd use grid as it gives you more control in two dimensions.

Comment: Yes, looks like it works ok with grid, but was wondering in case I miss something about flexbox.

Comment: Might have, but I don't understand enough about flex to know for sure. Perhaps give a relevant min width to the container??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS grid will give you easier (IMHO) control over the layout when you have to consider 2 dimensions.

Here's a simple example using your sizing of the elements.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 14px;
}

.button-item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 170px;
  height: 146px;
  border-radius: 27px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-item">1</div>
  <div class="button-item">2</div>
  <div class="button-item">3</div>
  <div class="button-item">4</div>
  <div class="button-item">5</div>
  <div class="button-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `row` class to your `.css` file, you will have 3 elements per row:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="button-item">1</div>
          <div className="button-item">2</div>
          <div className="button-item">3</div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="button-item">4</div>
          <div className="button-item">5</div>
          <div className="button-item">6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And add this to your `.css`:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: We're mapping these divs from api, so will not work here

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you added display none with this class.

```
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

after commenting on this class the 6 items appear correctly.

Comment: because you added also overflow-x: scroll. then the scroll should be visible. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-wood-ijs1lx?file=/src/styles.css:72-90)

Comment: That's not the issue. I don't need see scroll visible or not. I need this div scrolling horizontally on mobile same as for desktop

Comment: if you comment on the flex-wrap: wrap; the scroll will work vertically. if not they will work horizontally

Comment: Correct, I mentioned this in question :) I need this for 2 rows

Comment: I think grid instead of flex would be your best choice.

Comment: Yes, looks like this. Was thinking may be I miss something about flexbox.

Thanks anyway.